# Layout of progress bars with different horizontal positions

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I want to have a dynamic list of `QProgessBars` laid out vertically. But the thing is I want some of them to be moved horizontally. For example:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
   @@@@@@@@@@@
        @@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@
```

When I move widgets in the layout like this:

```
sl->move(10, 0);
```

nothing happens.

I also tried using `QGridLayout` with spacers:

```
QGridLayout * lay = new QGridLayout();
lay->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop);

for (int i = 1; i < 15; ++i) {
    QProgressBar * sl = new QProgressBar();
    QSpacerItem * sp = new QSpacerItem(10, 10 + i);
    lay->addWidget(sl, i, 0);
    lay->addItem(sp, i, 0);
}
```

I there a way to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do layout nesting, like they would do in html. Vertical layout with four (or three, if first row got only progress bar) horizontal layouts in it
[image: Example done in designer]

But using Grid as top layout would allow to add margins  at sides.
Of course you can do that programmatically. I've shown how that may look in Designer, but what designer actually does is to generate plain linear code. You can do that in for cycle instead.

Generated code:

```
   if (Dialog->objectName().isEmpty())
            Dialog->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("Dialog"));
        Dialog->resize(504, 377);
        gridLayoutWidget = new QWidget(Dialog);
        gridLayoutWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayoutWidget"));
        gridLayoutWidget->setGeometry(QRect(9, 9, 481, 351));
        gridLayout = new QGridLayout(gridLayoutWidget);
        gridLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout"));
        gridLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        horizontalLayout_3 = new QHBoxLayout();
        horizontalLayout_3->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_3"));
        horizontalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        horizontalLayout_3->addItem(horizontalSpacer);

        progressBar_2 = new QProgressBar(gridLayoutWidget);
        progressBar_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("progressBar_2"));
        progressBar_2->setValue(24);

        horizontalLayout_3->addWidget(progressBar_2);

        horizontalSpacer_2 = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        horizontalLayout_3->addItem(horizontalSpacer_2);


        gridLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayout_3, 1, 0, 1, 1);

        horizontalLayout_2 = new QHBoxLayout();
        horizontalLayout_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"));
        horizontalSpacer_3 = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        horizontalLayout_2->addItem(horizontalSpacer_3);

        progressBar_3 = new QProgressBar(gridLayoutWidget);
        progressBar_3->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("progressBar_3"));
        progressBar_3->setValue(24);

        horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(progressBar_3);


        gridLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayout_2, 2, 0, 1, 1);

        horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
        horizontalLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"));
        progressBar_4 = new QProgressBar(gridLayoutWidget);
        progressBar_4->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("progressBar_4"));
        progressBar_4->setValue(24);

        horizontalLayout->addWidget(progressBar_4);

        horizontalSpacer_4 = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        horizontalLayout->addItem(horizontalSpacer_4);


        gridLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayout, 3, 0, 1, 1);

        horizontalLayout_4 = new QHBoxLayout();
        horizontalLayout_4->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_4"));
        progressBar = new QProgressBar(gridLayoutWidget);
        progressBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("progressBar"));
        progressBar->setValue(24);

        horizontalLayout_4->addWidget(progressBar);


        gridLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayout_4, 0, 0, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi you need to use this [QGridLayout::addWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2) version. For instance, when you execute

```
grid->addWidget(w1, 0, 0, 1, 5);
grid->addWidget(w2, 1, 1, 2, 3);
grid->addWidget(w3, 3, 0, 1, 5);
```

your final gui will look something like this:

```
w1 w1 w1 w1 w1
   w2 w2 w2
   w2 w2 w2
w3 w3 w3 w3 w3
```

You can see the grid as a 2D-array. So w2 starts from `grid[1][1]` and spans over 2 rows and 3 columns. And since w2 spans over 2 rows, w3 should start at w1's row + 2 (i.e. 3).

Comment: That will work too, though it adds additional constraint on widgets. It might be a good thing or bad thing, depends on the form build. Grid layout with spanned  widgets are very useful to house panels into layout , which would hold other widgets